# Adding custom column / field into splunk result

Tags: splunk, spl

i am new to splunk and i am trying thing out on my own.
This might be an elementary question to most of you , but please be patient in trying to help me out.

```
| inputlookup "Wsp.csv"
| eval Outage = if(PublisherStatus = "Active", "1","0")
| eval _time=strptime(_time, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
| eval DayOfWeek=strftime(_time, "%A")
```

I am trying to add Outage and DayOfWeek to be displayed in the result.

i tried using field Outage and dayofweek but it doesn't display the rest of fields present in Wsp.csv

is it possible to display Wsp + Outage + dayofweek in the search result ? how ?

Answer (score 0):

What you've written will add the Outage and DayOfWeek fields to your results

If you want to reorder them, use `| table`:

```
| table _time Outage DayOfWeek <rest of fields, or *>
```

---

Also, `_time` shouldn't need to be converted into epoch time: it's an internal field that's always stored in epoch time (unless your CSV is weird)